# Read video file with cordova in android

Tags: android, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

Currently I am working on an `Ionic Cordova` app which let an user upload vdo and image from android device. I finished working image upload with help of cordova camera plugin which can choose photo from user phone and return base64 data. Now i am trying to get video as i did for image. But the video return data is file url which is sth like this `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A27227` . I don't know how to continue .

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use that url and pass it to a fileHandler routine and read the contents of the video.

I will forewarn you that it gets very complicated with iOS and Android using different file url formats. And there's no consistency between various Android devices that I ended up using a 3rd party plugin from the Ionic market place which is worth every penny and saved me months of development time and aggravation.